# Updating data when date is in condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am facing an issue to update the dataset with data type is date in Condition

Script:

```
UPDATE blse
   SET employment = 2066.3
 WHERE date = (i am not sure how)
   AND industry = 'Total Nonfarm'
   AND state = 'Alabama'
;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: even if the date was represented as 1/03/19?

Comment: We don't know what the date in the table looks like but if it's stored as a string that's a mistake in my opinion. You should always use the date/time data types: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html. `WHERE date::DATE = '01/03/19'::DATE`. When you cast to `DATE`, Postgres uses ISO format which is also the recommended way to store date/times. To see an example: `SELECT '01/03/19'::DATE;`

Comment: So that dataset is 4 columns Date (date) | employment (real) | industry (Character varying  | state (Character varying)

So I tried to use:
="UPDATE blse SET employment = "&B2&" WHERE date = "&A2&" AND industry= "&C2&" AND state="&D2&" ; "

But it did not work. ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Nonfarm"
LINE 1: ...2066.3 WHERE date=43496:: DATE AND industry=Total Nonfarm AN...

Answer (score 0):

The Date type formate is YYYY-MM-DD

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date = "1982-02-22";
```

so the command must be like

```sql
UPDATE blse 
SET employment = 2066.3 
WHERE 
    date = "2022-09-22" AND 
    industry = 'Total Nonfarm' AND 
    state = 'Alabama';
```

Comment: You may need to cast the comparator from a string to type `DATE`. Depending on how the date field's data type. `WHERE date = '2022-09-22'::DATE`

Comment: ="DELETE FROM blse WHERE date='2005-01-31'::DATE AND employment_1000s="&B2&" AND industry='"&C2&"' AND state='"&D2&"' ;"

it tells me that industry column does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use to_date() if you are casting from a string to accommodate a specific format. Example:

```
SELECT to_date('2000/JUN','YYYY/MON'); -- ok
SELECT '2000/JUN'::date; -- error
```

Check doc on to_date function:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html